# Should one use StringBuilder in a recursive function?

Tags: java, recursion, space-complexity

I understand that the purpose of `StringBuilder` (usually) is to avoid creating objects over and over in Java when iterating over strings, especially in a loop.

I'm wondering if it's worth it to use it in a recursive function that returns a string. In other words, which of the following is more efficient?

```
public String recursive(int n) {
    String retStr = "s";    

    if (n==0) {
        return retStr;
    }
    else {
        return retStr + recursive(n-1);
    }
}
```

or

```
public String recursive(int n) {
    String retStr = "s";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


    if (n==0) {
        return retStr;
    }
    else {
        return sb.append(retStr).append(recursive(n-1)).toString();
    }
}
```

If I had to guess, the first one seems less complex, because either way you have to create a new object, be it a `String` or a `StringBuilder`, every time, but I could be wrong.

Comment: If you create your `StringBuilder` inside the method, it won't work as intended.

Comment: Oh, I'm an idiot. If it's a class field it would work perfectly, you're right.

Comment: @Berger why are you saying it won't work as intended? The second example will recursively generate a `String` with the given number of `s`es `+ 1`, just like the first one that isn't using the `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @Mena I think because it won't save any memory space. It won't do it's job of not creating a new object every iteration if it's used that way. It will get the job done, just not well.

Comment: @Zaya ah ok - that was ambiguous to me.

Comment: @Mena : Well you're right, I misread how the method was working. But the creation of a new object at each call is indeed superfluous.

Comment: @Berger thanks for clarifying :)

Comment: Both your example are exactly the same in term of the bytecode produced. The compiler is already doing this optimisation. The optimization of user7294900 is however more useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add StringBuilder to recursive method:

```
public String recursive(int n, StringBuilder sb) {
    String retStr = "s";
    if (n==0) {
        return retStr;
    }
    else {
        return sb.append(retStr).append(recursive(n-1, sb)).toString();
    }
}
```

and call it

```
recursive(100, new StringBuilder());
```

Comment: Did you try it? IMHO, the output is far too long. And I wonder, wouldn't you return in the ==0 case sb.toString, and else just recursive (n-1, sb.append (retStr));

Answer (score 2):

if you are using java 8,

Since variables are in scope I think there is no need for StringBuilder.

> In summary, Java 8 seems not to introduce new optimizations for String
>   concatenation with the + operator. It means that using StringBuilder
>   manually is still required for specific cases where the compiler or
>   the JIT is not applying magic tricks. For instance, when lot of
>   substrings are concatenated to a String variable defined outside the
>   scope of a loop.

See more in [pellegrino](http://www.pellegrino.link/2015/08/22/string-concatenation-with-java-8.html)

and [dzone](https://dzone.com/articles/string-concatenation-performacne-improvement-in-ja)

Answer (score 1):

User7294900's idea to pass the StringBuilder is fine, but he is adding much too much.

```
public String recursive (int n, StringBuilder sb) {
    String retStr = "s";
    if (n==0) {
        return sb.toString ();
    }
    else {
        return recursive (n-1, sb.append (retStr));
    }
}
```

And - you should look this up, I'm unsure - doesn't the StringBuilder take hints, how big it will grow?

```
recursive (100, new StringBuilder (101));
```